# How to unhide the buttons present in another class in ios

Tags: ios, uibutton, hide, show-hide

I am new to ios development.I have three `UIButton` in present class,when I jump to the next class these three buttons are hidden and when I come back to present class I want these three buttons to be shown.can any one send me the code.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Describe your question better !!

Comment: When you go to next screen via push or model transition, you wont see the buttons at all and it will be visible only when you come back to this screen. Then why do you want to do this? Any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
if ([self isKindOfClass:[PresentClass class]]){
   self.button1.hidden = NO;
   self.button2.hidden = NO;
   self.button3.hidden = NO;
}
```

Using Introspection to do this. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Take `IBOutlets`/ Global objects for these 3 buttons. and

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[button1 setHidden:NO];
[button2 setHidden:NO];
[button3 setHidden:NO];

}
```